# ntpd & ntpdate won't set time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp

I recently purchased a new development board and, unfortunately, the edition of Linux provided doesn't sync with an NTP server automatically.

I have tried using "ntpd -dgq", however the output is just a constant series of transmitting to different servers. (ie it is stuck in a loop 'pinging' servers!)

I can use "ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com" and it will tell me how far off my machine is. However, the "-sd" flags basically does the same thing -- it doesn't set the time, it just tells me the offset.

Please note that the ntp service was disabled for both of these cases. Please also note this board is running a Linaro derivative (therefore it has apt-get utilities). If someone would like a pastebin please comment, however I feel it would do little good.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use ntpdate without `-q`?

Comment: Please add the content of your ntp.conf as well as any output rom the ntpd and ntpdate invocations. Is ntp.ubuntu.com the only server you have configured in your ntp.conf?